# Transpose returns list with empty strings

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and I am currently writing a word search in a grid game where it's possible to find words in diagonals, rows and columns. I use `Data.List.transpose` in order to create columns but the output always creates new empty strings. I've tried filter function but it doesn't change the output : `filter (not.null) (L.transpose y)`. The output looks like this : `["IYYPPOLFHTNMTDI","               ","UTVCGNVAEEZXEIR","               ","PDCPLTRUGSWTSQC","               ","GZEGUDGHSZTGSDT","               ","RMCEDJABPEUERTL","               ","ATTRVRXGKBRAMRA","               ","DZISDRASHAODEOP","               ","EVWWUWIXWBHGMMT","               ","ENAGCDYTYIOAOTO","               ","PRLCFFFEPDIVRKP","               ","EXZRNOKLOKPLYSO","               ","QSRESYZICYKUOLX"]`

The initial grid :

```
grid :: [String]
grid
     = ["I U P G R A D E E P E Q",
        "Y T D Z M T Z V N R X S",
        "Y V C E C T I W A L Z R",
        "P C P G E R S W G C R E",
        "P G L U D V D U C F N S",
        "O N T D J R R W D F O Y",
        "L V R G A X A I Y F K Z",
        "F A U H B G S X T E L I",
        "H E G S P K H W Y P O C",
        "T E S Z E B A B I D K Y",
        "N Z W T U R O H O I P K",
        "M X T G E A D G A V L U",
        "T E S S R M E M O R Y O",
        "D I Q D T R O M T K S L",
        "I R C T L A P T O P O X" ]
```

How can I solve this issue or is there a better way to transpose list of strings?

Comment: The strings aren't empty. The strings are filled with space ` `.That's because your grid contains a space at every even position, e.g. `I U P G`. If you remove those spaces, everything will turn out as you wanted.

Comment: Is this just a "how do I get it to print in this specific way" question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `transpose` treats the strings as lists of characters **including the spaces**.  If you tried:

```
transpose ["ABC",
           "DE ",
           "FGH"]
```

you'd get:

```
["ADF",
 "BEG",
 "C H"]
```

and you can see that all character, spaces included, are transposed.

For your particular case, there's an easy fix.  You can use `words` and `unwords` to convert `"A B C"` to `["A","B","C"]` and back before and after the transpose:

```
> import Data.List
> (map unwords . transpose . map words) ["A B C","D E F","G H I"]
["A D G","B E H","C F I"]
>
```

The reason your `filter` didn't work is that only the empty string is `null` -- a string of spaces is non-null.  You could have maybe used:

```
> import Data.Char
> filter (not . all isSpace) ["abc","   ","def"]
["abc","def"]
>
```

As a side note, you might want to reconsider whether you want to represent the grid with spaces internally in your program.  It seems like it would be easier to work with either:

```
[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]   :: [[String]]
```

or:

```
["abc","def","ghi"]   :: [[Char]]
```

internally and only add or subtract spaces when inputting or outputting a grid.

For the former representation, you can use `map words` and `map unwords` to convert back and forth.  For the latter, you can use:

```
> map (intersperse ' ') ["abc","def","ghi"]
["a b c","d e f","g h i"]
> map (concat . words) ["a b c","d e f","g h i"]
["abc","def","ghi"]
>
```